# PHP Multi-Dim Array , Replace value

Tags: php

```
// Source
Array
(
    [name] => ben
    [country] => ca
    [msg] => Array
        (
            [type] => mail
            [read] => 0
            [content] => hello world
        )
 )
// Change 
Array
(
    [msg] => Array
        (
            [read] => 1
        )
)
// Result
Array
(
    [name] => ben
    [country] => ca
    [msg] => Array
        (
            [type] => mail
            [read] => 1
            [content] => hello world
        )
)
$result = php_function($source,$change);
```

What php function allows this kind of transformation?

Comment: If all you're trying to do is change one field, why now `$source['msg']['read'] = 1;`?  Is `$change` the new value of `read`? or is it the field to change? If it's the field does it always get set to `1`? Will it always be withing `message`? Need some clarity here.

Comment: Hi imoda, the example you see here was simplified. I use php function to directly manipulate json objects stored in mysql. for ex: dbUpdate("tableName",$array,"where id =1") .  where array could be $array = array("data"=>array("read"=>"1")). I'd want my function to update mysql in such a way that only this variable is change ... hope this clarify a little : )  - it kinda emulate noMysql shema like mongoDB but using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function you are looking for is `array_merge_recursive_simple()`

See **[the comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#104145)** to the php.net documentation of `array_merge_resursive`

**Edit:** [This one](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#102379) is more elegant.

Comment: Thank you ! While its not a built-in function. It sure will do the trick.

Comment: Edit is shorter but, if you want foolproof, go with the original ;)